# Generate info_hash of torrent for xbtt

Tags: php, bittorrent

I am trying to create my own torrent tracker but dont know how to generate `info_hash` that is used `xbtt` to track torrents.

Is this possible with php?

I am using this function to bencode and decode http://paste.lisp.org/display/17178

Is this the correct hash?

```
$nn = file_get_contents('my.torrent');
$file = bdecode($nn);
$hash = sha1( bencode($file[info]) );
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [bittorrent specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) the info_hash is an *urlencoded 20-byte SHA1 hash of the value of the info key from the Metainfo file*.

You can calculate the sha1 hash of a string in php using the [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) function and url encode ot with the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

**UPDATE:**

Your method is not correct. You need to bdecode the torrent file, which you have already done. But you need to calculate the info_hash based on *the **value** of the **info** key from the Metainfo (torrent) file*.
When you have done that, you still need to urlencode the result, which it seems is also missing from your current implementation.

Comment: @Shishant: please see my updataed answer.